# C# intellisense library

Tags: c#, ide, intellisense

Is there any intellisense library for c# available to download?

I'd like to have a multi-line textbox in a winforms project which highlights c# keywords and (preferably) pops up a panel for listing possible keywords Just like VS IDE.

Comment: This is probably is what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087735/a-textbox-richtextbox-that-has-syntax-highlighting-c

Comment: If I google for "textbox intellisense" I get a lot of possible solutions :)

see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767622/how-do-i-implement-intellisense-like-suggestion-boxes-for-a-winforms-textbox
and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/Intellisense_popup.aspx

Comment: The other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087735/a-textbox-richtextbox-that-has-syntax-highlighting-c) asks for a syntax highlighter, but the accepted answer supports intellisense too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the C Sharp [project on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/AvalonEdit.aspx) for Syntax Highlighting.

There is also a similar question asked on stack overflow: [A textbox/richtextbox that has syntax highlighting? [C#]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087735/a-textbox-richtextbox-that-has-syntax-highlighting-c) .

Other open source projects include:

[dotNetFireball](http://dotnetfireball.codeplex.com/)

[Scintilla.NET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/)

[Editor.NET](http://www.qwhale.net/products/editor.htm)